# Search ontology tree by relationships in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, tree, ontology

i am working on a MySQL database with the following schema:

[image]

In which we save information from different ontologies ([exmp](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HUPO-PSI/psi-ms-CV/master/psi-ms.obo)). Some of the terms have relationships (exmp: MS:1000004, sample mass) which are indicated by `relationship:` or `is_a:`. For the sake of this question let's focus on the `is_a` relationships.
We now want to provide an option to search along these `is_a` relationships. So a function which we give `MS:1000004/sample mass` as input and get in return all Terms which are connected to it by an `is_a` relationship. But not only all terms directly connected to `MS:1000004`, but also all terms which are connected to the children and so on. This [image](https://www.frontiersin.org/files/Articles/26297/fgene-03-00197-r2/image_m/fgene-03-00197-g002.jpg) describes this a bit better, where `thing` would be `MS:1000004/sample mass` and everything below is what i want as result.
Currently we are using a rather unoptimized recursive function as a stored procedure to do this:

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getAllTermsByParentTerm`(IN `parentOntology` varchar(512))
BEGIN
    WITH RECURSIVE previous (accession, FK_OntologyName, name, definition, xrefvaluetype, isobsolete, fk_termAccession, relationshiptype, fk_termAccession_related, depth_level) AS (
        SELECT 
            t.accession, 
            t.FK_OntologyName, 
            t.name, 
            t.definition, 
            t.xrefvaluetype, 
            t.isobsolete, 
            trt.fk_termAccession, 
            trt.relationshiptype, 
            trt.fk_termAccession_related,
            0 depth_level
        FROM Term t
        INNER JOIN (TermRelationship AS trt, Term AS ref) ON(
            t.Accession = trt.FK_TermAccession
            AND trt.FK_TermAccession_Related = ref.Accession
            AND (trt.RelationshipType = `is_a` OR trt.RelationshipType = `part_of`)
            AND
                ( 
                    trt.FK_TermAccession_Related = ref.Accession
                    AND ref.Name = parentOntology
                )
        )
        UNION All
        SELECT 
            t2.accession, 
            t2.FK_OntologyName, 
            t2.name, 
            t2.definition, 
            t2.xrefvaluetype, 
            t2.isobsolete, 
            trt2.fk_termAccession, 
            trt2.relationshiptype, 
            trt2.fk_termAccession_related,
            (previous.depth_level+1) depth_level
        FROM Term t2
        INNER JOIN (TermRelationship AS trt2, previous) ON(
            t2.Accession = trt2.FK_TermAccession
            AND trt2.FK_TermAccession_Related = previous.Accession
        )
    )
    SELECT 
        t.Accession,
        t.FK_OntologyName,
        t.Name,
        t.Definition,
        t.xRefValueType,
        t.IsObsolete,
        p.depth_level
    FROM previous p
    Inner JOIN Term AS t ON (
        p.Accession = t.Accession
    );
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

To the question: i am not that experienced with MySQL so are there any options to optimize this function, or is MySQL the wrong tool overall?

Example rows:

Term

```
 
| Accession  | FK_OntologyName | Name                                                           | Definition                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   | XRefValueType                                                     | IsObsolete |
|------------|-----------------|----------------------------------------------------------------|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|-------------------------------------------------------------------|------------|
| TEST:0000000 | TEST          | Proteomics Standards Initiative Mass Spectrometry Vocabularies | "Proteomics Standards Initiative Mass Spectrometry Vocabularies." [PSI:MS]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |                                                                   |          0 |
| TEST:1000001 | TEST          | sample number                                                  | "A reference number relevant to the sample under study." [PSI:MS]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            | value-type:xsd\:string "The allowed value-type for this CV term." |          0 |
| TEST:1000002 | TEST          | sample name                                                    | "A reference string relevant to the sample under study." [PSI:MS]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            | value-type:xsd\:string "The allowed value-type for this CV term." |          0 |
| TEST:1000003 | TEST          | sample state                                                   | "The chemical phase of a pure sample, or the state of a mixed sample." [PSI:MS]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |                                                                   |          0 |
| TEST:1000004 | TEST          | sample mass                                                    | "Total mass of sample used." [PSI:MS]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        | value-type:xsd\:float "The allowed value-type for this CV term."  |          0 |
| TEST:1000005 | TEST          | sample volume                                                  | "Total volume of solution used." [PSI:MS]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    | value-type:xsd\:float "The allowed value-type for this CV term."  |          0 |
| TEST:1000006 | TEST          | sample concentration                                           | "Concentration of sample in picomol/ul, femtomol/ul or attomol/ul solution used." [PSI:MS]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   | value-type:xsd\:float "The allowed value-type for this CV term."  |          0 |
| TEST:1000007 | TEST          | inlet type                                                     | "The nature of the sample inlet." [PSI:MS]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |                                                                   |          0 |
| TEST:1000008 | TEST          | ionization type                                                | "The method by which gas phase ions are generated from the sample." [PSI:MS]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 |                                                                   |          0 |
| TEST:1000011 | TEST          | mass resolution                                                | "Smallest mass difference between two equal magnitude peaks so that the valley between them is a specified fraction of the peak height." [PSI:MS]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            | value-type:xsd\:string "The allowed value-type for this CV term." |          0 |
| TEST:1000012 | TEST          | resolution measurement method                                  | "Which of the available standard measures is used to define whether two peaks are separate." [PSI:MS]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |                                                                   |          0 |
| TEST:1000014 | TEST          | accuracy                                                       | "Accuracy is the degree of conformity of a measured mass to its actual value." [PSI:MS]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      | value-type:xsd\:float "The allowed value-type for this CV term."  |          0 |
| TEST:1000015 | TEST          | scan rate                                                      | "Rate in Th/sec for scanning analyzers." [PSI:MS]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            | value-type:xsd\:float "The allowed value-type for this CV term."  |          0 |
| TEST:1000016 | TEST          | scan start time                                                | "The time that an analyzer started a scan, relative to the start of the MS run." [PSI:MS]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    | value-type:xsd\:float "The allowed value-type for this CV term."  |          0 |
| TEST:1000018 | TEST          | scan direction                                                 | "Direction in terms of m/z of the scan for scanning analyzers (low to high, or high to low)." [PSI:MS]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |                                                                   |          0 |
| TEST:1000019 | TEST          | scan law                                                       | "Describes the function in control of the m/z scan (for scanning instruments). Commonly the scan function is linear, but in principle any function can be used." [PSI:MS]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    |                                                                   |          0 |
| TEST:1000021 | TEST          | reflectron state                                               | "Status of the reflectron, turned on or off." [PSI:MS]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |                                                                   |          0 |
| TEST:1000022 | TEST          | TOF Total Path Length                                          | "The length of the field free drift space in a time of flight mass spectrometer." [PSI:MS]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   | value-type:xsd\:float "The allowed value-type for this CV term."  |          0 |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          | value-type:xsd\:int "The allowed value-type for this CV term."    |          0 |
```

TermRelationship

```
| ID     | FK_TermAccession | RelationshipType | FK_TermAccession_Related | FK_OntologyName |
|--------|------------------|------------------|--------------------------|-----------------|
| 0 | TEST:1000001          | is_a             | TEST:0000000             | TEST            |
| 1 | TEST:1000002          | is_a             | TEST:0000000             | TEST            |
| 2 | TEST:1000003          | is_a             | TEST:1000002             | TEST            |
| 3 | TEST:1000004          | is_a             | TEST:1000002             | TEST            |
| 4 | TEST:1000005          | is_a             | TEST:1000002             | TEST            |
| 5 | TEST:1000006          | is_a             | TEST:1000002             | TEST            |
| 6 | TEST:1000007          | is_a             | TEST:1000002             | TEST            |
| 7 | TEST:1000008          | is_a             | TEST:1000007             | TEST            |
| 8 | TEST:1000011          | is_a             | TEST:1000007             | TEST            |
| 9 | TEST:1000022          | is_a             | TEST:0000000             | TEST            |
```

Expected outcome is to execute the function for `TEST:0000000/Proteomics Standards Initiative Mass Spectrometry Vocabularies` and get all the following terms, because they are child/grandchild terms to `TEST:0000000`.

```
TEST:1000001
TEST:1000002
TEST:1000003
TEST:1000004
TEST:1000005
TEST:1000006
TEST:1000007
TEST:1000008
TEST:1000011
TEST:1000022
```

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result. How fast do you want these searches to be? With the right indexes they could run quite fast (within a limited depth, of course).

Comment: The Main problem is, that the current function, which i posted above, does not work for example for `OBI:0100026/organism` ([see here](http://www.ontobee.org/ontology/OBI?iri=http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/OBI_0100026)). which has more or less the whole ncbitaxon ontology as child. As we have around 2.551.869 Terms and 2.764.984 TermRelationships.

So posting some rows of sample data might not be enough to correctly identity the issues.

Comment: Graph databases are lot more suitable for storing ontologies, rather than an RDBMS!

Comment: If it helps, the whole database scheme can be seen [here](https://github.com/nfdi4plants/Swate/blob/developer/.db/mysql-dump/SwateDB.sql). And i can also upload a dump somewhere with one of the smaller ontologies as example.

Answer (score 0):

Some of these may help performance:

```
t:  INDEX(Accession)
trt:  INDEX(FK_TermAccession_Related,  relationshiptype, FK_TermAccession)
trt:  INDEX(FK_TermAccession, FK_TermAccession_Related,  relationshiptype)
ref:  INDEX(Accession,  Name)
previous:  INDEX(Accession,  depth_level)
```

Please use `JOIN...ON` instead of `(TermRelationship AS trt, Term AS ref)`

What table is `parentOntology` in?

`trt.FK_TermAccession_Related = ref.Accession` show up redundantly.

Comment: `parentOntology` is a bit missleading it points to `Term.Name`